# Dagger 2 não gera os componentes

Tags: java, android

Sempre que tento dar `build` no meu projeto o seguinte ***erro*** ocorre:

> `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V`

Segue minhas classes responsáveis pela injeção de dependência:

**ApplicationModule**

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private static final String APP_ID = "id";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "secret";

    private final Application mApplication;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Client provideClient(Application application) {
        return new Client.Builder(APP_ID, APP_SECRET, application).build();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(MainApplication application);

    Application getApplication();

    Client getClient();

}
```

**MainApplication**

```
public class MainApplication extends android.app.Application {

    private ApplicationComponent component;

    @Inject
    Client client;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ...

        component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();
        component.inject(this);
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

}
```

E meu **gradle.build (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.mobi.santor.agora"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '25.1.0'
final DAGGER_VERSION = '2.8'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'kinvey-android-2.10.6', ext: 'aar')

    // AppCompat dependencies
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"

    // Dagger dependencies
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"

    // Network dependencies
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // Utils dependencies
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**build.gradle (Module:project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Silas, isso me parece uma incompatibilidade do Dagger com o Jack. Vi também que usa Retrolambda com java 8, isso é mesmo necessário? Minha sugestão é seguir a solução temporária proposta por esse [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/557) do dagger.

Comment: @Wakim removi o Retrolambda, mas ainda assim ocorre o erro.

Comment: Hmm, remover o Retrolambda de fato não resolve o problema, parecia ser apenas redundante dado que está usando Java 8. Poderia incluir o seu gradle do projeto?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Minha outra sugestão seria atualizar o seu build tools para a versão `2.3.0-beta3`, e usar o gradle 3.3 (basta rodar o comando `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 3.3` para atualizar).

Comment: Fiz isso, mas as bibliotecas do kinvey, calligraphy e AppCompat que estavam sendo utilizadas não estão sendo encontradas .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a [resposta de gk5885](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916466/dagger-2-not-generating-components/41962377#41962377), atualizei o Guava. No meu caso, tive que apagar o `guava-18.0.jar` da pasta `lib` exigido pelo Kinvey para que o Dagger adicionasse automaticamente a versão mais compatível.